# Error while uploading DICOM image to dcm4chee

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

[Log Image: dcm image using dcmsnd utility.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMXUz.png)

When I try to upload dcm image to the pacs It generates the error.

> 2016-07-21 12:24:46,017 WARN  STORESCU->DCM4CHEE (TCPServer-1-1)
>   [org.dcm4chex.archive.mbean.FileSystemMgt2Service] Failed to create
>   directory /var/lib/bahmni/dcm4chee-2.18.1-psql/server/default/archive
>   - try to switch to next configured storage directory 2016-07-21 12:24:46,026 ERROR STORESCU->DCM4CHEE (TCPServer-1-1)
>   [org.dcm4chex.archive.mbean.FileSystemMgt2Service] High Water Mark
>   reached on storage file system FileSystem[pk=1, archive,
>   groupID=ONLINE_STORAGE, aet=DCM4CHEE, ONLINE, RW+, userinfo=null] - no
>   alternative storage file system configured for file system group
>   ONLINE_STORAGE 2016-07-21 12:24:46,027 WARN  STORESCU->DCM4CHEE
>   (TCPServer-1-1) [org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.storescp.StoreScpService]
>   org.dcm4che.net.DcmServiceException

Here is the some log which shows in the dcm4chee.
I tried to give permission for the directory but still it gives an error to me.

I am not getting any solution for the error please provide any solution if any one have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your current file system is full.

You should try adding another file system. [Here](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/File+System+Management+Service) you can find additional instructions about this using the MBeans based management interface.